# Spring @ConditionalOnProperty annotation not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, annotations

I have a property defined inside a property file: `property=true`

Then I have `SomeClass.java` class , which *should* create a Property Configuration bean *only* if the property `property` is set to true.

This is my `SomeClass` class:

```
public class SomeClass {

  //this is the proerty which I set to true or false
  @Value("${property}")
  private String property;

  //this is the bean which needs to be created conditionally based on the property but at the moment it does not get created
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name="${property}", havingValue="true")
  public PropertyConfiguration propertyConfig() {
    // doesnt print anything because the bean does not get created
    System.out.print(property);
  }
}
```

If I add the `matchIfMissing = true` inside the `@ConditionalOnProperty`, just to experiment and to see what is the value of `property`, then the bean *does* get created and I see that the value of `property` is `true`.

If I remove the `matchIfMissing = true`, leave the condition as `@ConditionalOnProperty(name="${property}", havingValue="true")` and change the property `property=true` from `true` to `false` the bean is never created (neither for `true` nor for `false`).

What should I do s.t. the bean gets created conditionally, based on the property?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please add `@Configuration` above your class.

The component scan does not include your class, to do so it is required to add a `@Component` or any other inherited annotation on top of your class. Then your `@Bean` should be created from spring.

Hope this helps.